# How to make redirected input count as command output

Tags: linux, redirection, diff, input

I have a simple C console program that takes some keyboard input and outputs prompts and calculations. I also have two text files: a file with input for the program, and a file that contains the output the program should give.

The problem is that

```
$ c_program < input_file > output_file
```

doesn't echo the input to the output file. The output_file will have just the prompts and calculations, without the redirected input. How do I make the input dovetail with the output so that the output file will look just like it does when input is given with the keyboard?

For example, here's a sample session:

```
Input number of feet traveled: 5
Input number of seconds: 2.5
Average speed is 2.0 feet per second
```

But when redirecting input and output, we get:

```
Input number of feet traveled: Input number of seconds: Average speed is 2.0 feet per second
```

How can I make the second look like the first?

Comment: You will have to change the C program to output the inputs. If you redirected input, how would it be synchronised with the output?

Answer (score 0):

For scripting an interaction with a program while capturing interaction in the correct order, you might want to look at more advanced tools than just input and output redirection.

For example, using [**expect(1)**](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) you could script your interaction like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn "./c_program"    
expect "Input number of feet traveled: "
send "5\r"
expect "Input number of seconds: "
send "2.5\r"
expect eof
```

When you execute the script, you'll get the transcript of the entire automated interaction.